# How to remove applications that are pinned to the desktop in AOSP?

Tags: android-source

I'm making a custom ROM based on the Nexus 5 variant for Android 5.1 and I need to remove the default applications that are pinned to the desktop.

To make things clear - I don't care about the applications being availalble from the launcher, I just don't want them on the desktop.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Go to](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/packages/apps/Launcher2/res/xml/default_workspace.xml): `/packages/apps/Launcher2/res/xml/default_workspace.xml`

Or `/packages/apps/Launcher3/res/xml/default_workspace_*x*.xml` (Depends on the version you are building).

and modify the file as you wish.

**Please note:**

This method worked for me, keep in mind that the vendor will usually overlay this setting. Make sure to look in your specific `device` sub-directory for overlayed on `packages/apps/Launcher3`

Comment: Yeah, but that wasn't it though... Mine was overlayed by the vendor which confused me. I added it to your answer